# How to convert a multiple barplot to a percentage barplot in R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on converting the data into percentages. I have been trying to use pipe function and mutate, But it did not seem to work. Kindly suggest me the changes to be made

```r
 data$Number.of.Beetle <- trimws(data$Number.of.Beetle)
#> Error in data$Number.of.Beetle: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  lvls <- unique(data$Number.of.Beetle)
#> Error in data$Number.of.Beetle: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
 lvls <- stringr::str_sort(lvls, numeric = TRUE)
#> Error in stri_sort(x, decreasing = decreasing, na_last = na_last, opts_collator = stri_opts_collator(locale, : object 'lvls' not found
 data$Number.of.Beetle <- factor(data$Number.of.Beetle, levels = lvls)
#> Error in data$Number.of.Beetle: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
 
   lvls2 <- unique(data$Building.Age)
#> Error in data$Building.Age: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  lvls2 <- lvls2[c(2, 3, 1)]
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'lvls2' not found
  data$Building.Age <- factor(data$Building.Age, levels = lvls2)
#> Error in data$Building.Age: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
 
   
   ggplot(data, aes(x = Locality.Division))+
     geom_bar(aes(fill = Number.of.Beetle), position = "dodge")+
     facet_wrap(~ Building.Age) +
     labs(title = "Comparison between Number of beetle, Locality division and Age of the building",
          subtitle ="Building age") 
#> Error in ggplot(data, aes(x = Locality.Division)): could not find function "ggplot"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
[image: The image created here represents the data in counts]

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible format? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). How do you get the plot that you have shared if everything returns an error?

Comment: You can use `position="fill"` instead of `dodge` to achieve this. You don't need any other calculations separately. But as @RonakShah mentioned a reproducible example will help us answer more efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, but this code did give me the plot without an error. But the reprex I provided is showing lots of errors. I tried restarting the R session but the reprex turned out to look the same.

Comment: I just wanted to have these very same bars in terms of percentages. Sorry but not to "fill"